# List of lists changes the first list (Even when making a copy of the list)

Tags: python, list, recursion

```
def get_squares(self):
    if self.check_full():
        self.all_squares.append(self.square.copy())
    while not self.is_placeable() or self.square in self.all_squares:
        if self.square[self.i][self.j] == self.n * self.n:
            self.go_back()
        else:
            self.square[self.i][self.j] += 1

    if self.i != self.n - 1 or self.j != self.n - 1:
        self.go_forward()

    self.get_squares()
    return self.all_squares
```

I tried making a recursive function. Once it appends the first list (`self.all_squares.append(self.square.copy())`), that copied list changes every time the variable `self.square` changes which interfere with my program, causing it to reach the maximum recursion depth.

Some help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: what id the data type of the object inside all_squares?

Comment: @balderman all_square is a list of 'squares', and a square is a 2-dimensional integer list.

Comment: look at deep copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`copy()` does not create a deep copy. It creates a shallow copy, meaning that the result is a new list containing the same values as the original. If the values have reference types, as is the case with lists and other objects, the new list will contain references to the same instances referenced by the original list.

The easiest way to create a deep copy of a list of lists is using the function `map` and calling copy from there.

```
deepcopy = list(map(lambda x: x.copy(), original))
```

In your specific case:

```
self.all_squares.append(list(map(lambda x: x.copy(), self.square)))
```

but please, put the `list(map(...))` thing into its own method because like this, the line is not very readable ^^

The call to `list` with the result of `map` as the argument is necessary because map does not return a list but a sequence.